# Command not found in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder containing some files including ".bar" files. Now I would like to make a bash script that finds these ".bar" files and creates a folder with the same name. However I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I use:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="folder"

for filename in ${PATH}/*.bar; do
    mkdir $(basename ${filename%.*})
done
```

It seems to work when I use it in a terminal, but when I put in in a script it fails with the error: "basename: command not found" and "mkdir: command not found". How can I get this to work?

Comment: `PATH` is a very important reserved variable. Because you're replacing its value in the second line, you whole script breaks.

Comment: @Robin479. That fixes it indeed. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash
folderpath="folder"

for filename in "${folderpath}"/*.bar; do
    mkdir "$(basename "${filename%.*}")"
done
```

PATH is an internal shell variable and shouldn't be used in your shell script.

Comment: *All* all-uppercase variables are reserved for use by the shell.